# how to set Content-Type other than application/json

Tags: json, afnetworking

I'm trying to send a REST API to my server by AFNetworking2.0, our server only accepts `Content-Type` as `application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json` when i send the request, it is json format indeed,

```
    self.operationMgr = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    self.operationMgr.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    operationMgr.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    operationMgr.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    self.operationMgr.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet       setWithObject:@"application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json"];
    [self.operationMgr.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [self.operationMgr.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [self.operationMgr POST:@"https://ip/rest" parameters:body
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* task, NSError* error){
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

but it does not seem to be working, `Content-Type` always be modified to `application/json` in my request, who can help to solve this problem? many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As of AFNetworking 2.2.3, all you need to do is:

```
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

More detail in [this Github issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1884).

---

In AFNetworking 2, serialization has been abstracted out into "request serializers" and "response serializers".  The classes are designed to be subclassed to handle any special cases like yours.

For your specific question, the simplest approach would be:

1. Create a subclass of `AFJSONRequestSerializer`.
2. Override the method that generates the URL Request like so:

   ```
   - (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                  withParameters:(id)parameters
                                           error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
       NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[super requestBySer…etc.] mutableCopy];
       [mutableRequest setValue:@"application/vnd.mycom.mycom-csc+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       return mutableRequest;
   }
   ```
3. Tell your operation manager to use your newly created subclass:

   ```
   operationMgr.requestSerializer = [MyAwesomeJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
   ```

I'm not sure if the behavior you're seeing is expected or not (the documentation doesn't match the implementation exactly).  I [opened an issue on Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1884) to discuss it.  Either way, the workaround I propose here should resolve the issue if you just want to get it working.

Comment: thanks very much to Aaron Brager's suggestion, now i modify the source code of the AFNetworking for my special case, it works now