# Unable to set content type in AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have a web-service which requires Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have set the headers but it does not changes as I can see in the request logs. Below is the code and request log

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.net/api/"];

    // Initialize Request Operation Manager
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    // Configure Request Operation Manager
    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

    // Send Request
    [manager GET:@"Account/Register" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Process Response Object
        NSLog(@"Register Response: %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Handle Error
        NSLog(@"Register Response Error: %@",[error description]);
    }];
```

But when I look into the request, Content-Type is not changed. Here is the request details

```
    ErrorDomain=AFNetworkingErrorDomainCode=-1011"Request failed: bad request (400)"UserInfo=0x109559a40{
      AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x109709260>{
        URL: http: //example.net/api/Account/Register
      }{
        statuscode: 400,
        headers{
          "Cache-Control"="no-cache";
          "Content-Length"=142;
          "Content-Type"="application/json; charset=utf-8";
          Date="Mon, 10 Mar 2014 14:30:52 GMT";
          Expires="-1";
          Pragma="no-cache";Server="Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
         "Set-Cookie"="xxxxx;Path=/;Domain=example.net, WAWebSiteSID=xxxxxxx; Path=/; HttpOnly";"X-AspNet-Version"="4.0.30319";"X-Powered-By"="ASP.NET";
        }
      },

  NSLocalizedDescription=Requestfailed: badrequest(400),
  NSErrorFailingURLKey=http: //example.net/api/Account/Register
}
```

**How can I set Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?**

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22275175/1445366 (I can't flag as duplicate since that answer is neither upvoted nor accepted).

Comment: @AaronBrager, I tried your code but still Content-Type is application/json

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're setting the response serializer, not the request serializer.  Don't you just want to do `manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`?  Why are you using JSON at all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set ResponseSerializer to manager.
Please user below code will work for you.

```
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.net/api/"];

// Initialize Request Operation Manager
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// Configure Request Operation Manager
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

// Send Request
[manager GET:@"Account/Register" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Process Response Object
    NSLog(@"Register Response: %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Handle Error
    NSLog(@"Register Response Error: %@",[error description]);
}];
```