# AFNetworking 2.0: Passing header information

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am new to AFNetworking and I know how to pass URL parameters. But how would I pass headers into the same call.

I am also subclassing my AFHTTPSessionManager

See my code below:

```
- (void)getExpenses:(NSString *)page
                success:(void (^) (NSArray *myExpenses))success
                failure:(RequestFailureBlock)failure
{
    NSString *resourceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/expenses/", APIBaseURLString];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"page":page, @"Authorization": APIAuthorization};

    [self getExpenses:resourceURL parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];

}
```

Comment: are you using get method or post method?

Comment: see the documentation http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue%3aforHTTPHeaderField%3a

Comment: I am using GET Method.

Comment: FYI, I am subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager. I can't figure this out. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

[setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken is deprecated](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/cd9a80f) due to [servers having different requirements about how the access token](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1974) is sent (token, bearer, etc)

michaels answer otherwise is correct, use

`[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"Some-Value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Header-Field"];`

or

`[self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"" password:@""];`

for basic auth

Answer (score 0):

You set header values on the [requestSerializer](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/requestSerializer) property of AFHTTPSessionManager:

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"Some-Value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Header-Field"];
```

EDIT:

It looks like you're trying to set authorization; there is a method for that too:

```
[self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"" password:@""];
// OR
[self.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken:@""];
```

If you need to set the `Content-Type` header, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275175/3482071) on how to do that

Comment: Note that this won't work for the `Content-Type` header; see https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1884

Comment: I specifically need to set Content-Type

Comment: Edited my answer with a link to how to set `Content-Type` header

Comment: Says  setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken is deprecated.

Comment: Which version? I don't see it deprecated in the [2.2.1 docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithToken:)

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated because there is no common convension. User `-setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: instead`

Comment: There is JSON error when you try to set authorization header with value which contain colon (:) using setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: method.